# Can I run a CRON job for an hour

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, cron

I am creating an app that requires a CRON job to be executed every 60 seconds.

My host only allows a CRON job once an hour.

I was wondering if I could create a script like this:

```
$i = 0;
while(1==1){
// update database code

delay(10000);

// $i is incremented once a minute/10000ms
$i++;
}

//if $i reaches 60 we know that the CRON has run for an hour
if($i == 60){
die();
}
```

Is this recommended? Will this accurately update my database every 60 seconds?

I don't mind if the script will be a few seconds out.

I understand I will need to set my `php.ini` to increase the max execution time.

Comment: Why not run a smaller cronjob every 60 seconds?

Comment: @DarylGill _My host only allows a CRON job once an hour._

Comment: [PHP Sleep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)

Comment: Why the down vote? The sleep function looks quite good!

Comment: You may want to get a timestamp before your database work and calculate the run time of updating your query. Subtract that from ten minutes and use the result as your delay. This could make your timing more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work, if the hosting allows overriding of `max_execution_time`.
You can do it right in the script, by the way: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0)`. And be careful with memory. It's not C/C++, of course, but still a good idea to watch variables initialization and loops.

Comment: Do you think I should consider a host that will allow a CRON to be ran every minute instead?

Comment: That is an option, of course. Still I think nothing is critical in using sleep, even though it's not co common thing.